# see all logins and attempts in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, login, event-log

There any way to get the dates and times of logins on a computer with windows 7 (Local and Remote)

I read this [article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/monitor-attempts-to-access-and-change-settings-on-your-computer), but in events viewer I cant see any login (All events are other types)

We believe that a malicious operator performs nightly procedures, on some computers of the company, but we need some evidence to know that he did.

This person has access to the active directory (He know many passwords), for maintenance, but we believe this performing malicious actions of some members of the organization

[image]

Comment: [Enable Account Auditing](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/windows-7-what-is-account-auditing-and-how-to-enable-it/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable Account Auditing Settings:

1. Click <kbd>Start</kbd>
2. Type `secpol.msc`
3. Right click the `secpol.msc` program option and select `Run as Administrator`
4. Navigate to `Local Policy > Audit Policy`
5. Right click the `Audit account logon events` policy option
6. Select `Properties`.
7. Check both the `Success` and `Failure` check boxes.

Then the event log will contain the logon and logoff records. However, you will need to make sure general users don't have the ability to clear your event logs or change the audit policy settings otherwise your records may not be reliable.

Comment: First thanks, but I can check both options, beacuse this warning `this configuration can not be applied if another policy is configured to override audit policy category level. For more information see Q921468` (my traslate I'm on a windows in another language) click the link, but no exist

Comment: @jasilva I presume you are running `secpol.msc` from an administrator account (I updated the answer just in case), so try using `rsop.msc` to determine if a higher-level policy (Site/Domain/Organisational Unit) is blocking access and thus which policy level is the culprit.